# Reading file returns empty string

Tags: node.js, parsing, fs

I am trying to parse an ICS file (calendar). I had troubles at first with my parser because it always returned me some "empty objects" as data. I tried to open, read and display the file content to see if something was missing : and it appears that even the simple `fs.readFile` function does not return anything. Or perhaps an empty string.

The file parsed is not very big (around 50kb), but my code is working when I shorten to file to be only 2kb for instance.
Here is the code used :

```
parse(filePath) {

    fs = require('fs');

    fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', function(err, data){
        if(err){
            return console.log(err);
        };

        console.log("data : " + data.toString());
        response = data;
    });


}
```

Very simple and basic code.
To sum up  : it works if I shorten the file, it doesn't work if I keep it with its original size.
Has anyone already faced this issue ?

**EDIT**
The size does not matter. I am downloading this file from a remote server. If the script downloads the file and parses it, it returns an empty string.
I the script downloads it, then I open the file with GEdit, save & close, then start the parser, everything is going fine.

The strange part is that I gave chmod 777 on this file, I don't see how opening it with gedit is making the process working...

Comment: Is your ics file encoded in utf-8?

Comment: Yes it is, I checked it several times.

Comment: Does it work with readFileSync ? To exclude timing issues

Comment: Unfortunately not. I identified the source of the issue and edited my post.